# How to apply 9 patch images in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, nine-patch

I have an Image with width to height ratio 7:2. 
Currently I am using `scaleType="fitXY"` with `android:width="match_parent"` and `android:height="wrap_content"`. 
But due to irregular scaling the text in the image is skewed and I am not get a quality Image. Can using 9 patch images solve the issue what other workaround do I have?

Comment: nine patch image is used to cater a single image to all types of Screen resolution.You can try using nine patch , but while creating you have to draw the black lines according to the ratio of your height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could indeed use a 9 patch image, but you would need to stretch the non-text parts of the image so the text would not stretch. This would most likely give undesirable results with possibly tiny text in a large scaled image.

A better way would to have a textless 9patch image and use it as a background to a TextView and scale the text with textView.setTextSize(x) to fit the image.

Eg.

```
    TextView theText = new TextView(this);
    theText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourninepatch);
    float scale = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int screenWidth = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    float fontSize = screenWidth / 26 / scale;
    theText.setTextSize(fontSize);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike. The text is harcoded in the image.. Is there any workaround

Comment: You could manually scale the image if you know how much of the width of the screen the image is taking, for example, if the image was to take half the width of the screen you could scale it by adding it to a layout using.. int screenWidth = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels; yourLayout.addview(yourimage,screenWidth/2, screenWidth/7);